# How could I use LINQ to filter out strings starting with a variety of sub-strings?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Let's say I have `var lines = IEnumerable<string>`, and `lines` contains a variety of lines whose first 1..n characters exclude them from a process. E.g lines starting with '*', 'E.g.', 'Sample', etc.

The list of exclusion tokens is variable and known only at runtime, so

```
lines.Where(l => !l.StartsWith("*") && !l.StartsWith("E.g.") && ...
```

becomes somewhat problematic.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
 List<string> exceptions = new List<string>() { "AA", "EE" };

 List<string> lines = new List<string>() { "Hello", "AAHello", "BHello", "EEHello" };

 var result = lines.Where(x => !exceptions.Any(e => x.StartsWith(e))).ToList();
 // Returns only "Hello", "BHello"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();    //add some values
List<string> exclusion=new List<string>();  //add some values

var result = lines.Except(exclusion, new MyComparer());
```

Where:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string x, string y) { return x.StartsWith(y); }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj) { //some code }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't warrant a comparer imo.
Upvoting for use of a comparer regardless of context is silly.

Comment: I much prefer Blachshma's answer, but yours is neat, and earns you + 1 for teaching me about `Except`.